# Which side is the capacitor negative on this board? (IO/10 marking)

Tags: capacitor, polarity, negative

I removed a capacitor (C1 (400v/15uf) - highlighted in the picture) from this board to test on another board and now I want to put it back but I can't figure out the polarity. The traditional symbol for negative side is not there but a (IO/10) marking which doesn't show up in Google searches. Any suggestions appreciated. Refer picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the positive solder pad: -

[image]

It's a commonly used symbolic representation of a polarized capacitor based on [this](https://uk.farnell.com/capacitor-types-and-performance) where the unfilled-box part of the symbol represents the positive electrode: -

[image]

Comment: thanks, soldered as mentioned and started working.

Comment: Your image on the bottom (which is missing a source, by the way) lists the curved plate capacitor as "non-polarized", but I've never seen it used that way. The curved plate is always negative and it always refers to a polarized capacitor. While it might be *possible* to use it to indicate which side should get the outer layer of a film capacitor, I would regard that as needlessly confusing--that would be better served by an annotation in plain english (or whatever language).

Comment: Though I'll accept that it may have been a standard usage in the past. It would just be confusing today, to engineers around my age (not quite 30).

Comment: @Hearth the link source is attached to the word "this" in the sentence above.

Answer (score 5):

I'm amazed at Andy's confidence in a symbol's meaning.
Because danger is so great here if you get polarity wrong, double-checking your choice using other methods is recommended.

I can make a guess how copper connects from the photo. It appears that the two left-most diodes (D3, D4) have their anodes connected together, and also connect to the top pad of C1.
[image: OP's photo, annotated]
The two right-most diodes (D1, D2) have their cathodes joined, and also connect to an array of vias going to copper on the backside. I'm guessing that these connect to C1's bottom pad (flipping the board to verify would be advised).
I would triple check all this guessing by sketching out a circuit diagram to see if it makes sense electrically:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSLmfu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This schematic makes sense electrically - it is a full bridge rectifier. The diode polarity is pretty much industry-standard having cathodes marked, here with a white bar (difficult to see in the photo).

This schematic may not reflect actual circuitry, but it should suffice to determine which way C1 should be installed.
One wonders how C1 and these four diodes survive the turn-on surge. The 1.1 ohm resistor might possibly be involved to limit the turn-on current. A thermistor is often used to charge C1 - I would hope it is installed off-photo.

Comment: As another data point, my (self-made) radial electrolytic capacitor footprints have the silk screen circle on the (+) lead since that's the longer lead and for hand assembly it makes a target for the first lead to be inserted. Getting the polarity wrong would be .. exciting.

Comment: Is it just me or does it look like the mains wires are connected contrary to what the L and N labels say?

Comment: @AndrewMorton you've pointed out *another* "standard" that can bite (over 'ere its black/white, not blue/brown). Another thing to check - which one of these is closer to earth. Colours and their meanings should be limited to resistor bands - I think that standard is fairly reliable, although I've seen some confusion between orange and red, and often between brown and violet, against body colour.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Well you can rectify that by flipping the mains plug the other way (if you have flippable plugs). The wires don't know which way the plug is inserted to socket.

Comment: @Justme Isn't it the diodes that rectify, not the mains plug? I'll get my coat...

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Tantalum capacitor packages also mark the positive side by convention. Sometimes a footprint follows the tantalum convention, other time it's a generic electrolytic footprint. Without pre-checking before soldering, firework is guaranteed...